# How to use multiple 'commands' in the same function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, command

I'm trying to figure out how, if even possible, can you perform more than one command within a Haskell function? For example, if I had:

```
foo [[a]] = print (head a) --AND -- map (head of everything but the first value)
```

How would I go about doing something like that? Is there a function which I could use in place of --AND-- which would allow me to perform both commands on the list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `do` notation, which combined with properly formed pattern matching would get your desired behavior:

```
foo :: Show a => [[a]] -> IO ()
foo xs = do
    print $ head $ head xs -- first value in the 2D list
    print $ map head $ tail xs -- Skip first sublist with tail
```

Comment: That works great and it also just about fits what i'm trying to do. However, how would you go about calling the latter command recursively? i.e Print the head(first line), then print the head of the tail lists(second line) recursively, so as to print all values within the tail lists in the same format(head-by-head). Is this doable within this context?

Comment: @JengaBlock Are you wanting to print the list transposed?  Could you provide an example input and output to make it more clear what you're wanting to do?

Comment: Sure, if I had [[5],[4,3],[7,6]], I'd like the output to be:
5\n
4,7\n
3,6\n
And then for it to end when it hits all empty lists.
EDIT: Sorry, not sure how to go to a new line in the comment section, \n signifies a new line above.

Comment: @JengaBlock Yes, you're just wanting to do a list transposition.  Look at the function `transpose` in `Data.List`.  It'll reorder the list exactly as you want, and then you can just print it out normally or use it in another calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Control.Arrow module has many combinators for wiring inputs to functions in interesting ways. Fanouts, fan-ins, etc.

On my phone, but something like `print (<<<)  head (&&&) map ( f . tail) $ input` . That is wrong functions and order of operations, but gives a hint of the flavor. Check the module docs.